# Recoding factor levels for wind direction

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling, recode

I have the following factors I wish to recode into main wind direction components. Returning with an error I don't understand. I could really use some help with solving this.

The variable W.G.Dir is of factor form with 16 levels.

```
weather$W.G.Dir <- factor(recode(weather$W.G.Dir,
  `Southerly` = c(
    "SSE", "S",
    "SSW"
  ),
  `Easterly` = c("ENE", "E", "ESE"),
  `Northerly` = c("NNE", "N", "NNW"),
  `Westerly` = c("WNW", "W", "WSW"),
  `S'East` = "SE", `S'West` = "SW", `N'East` =
    "NE", `N'West` = "NW"
))
```

Error: `Southerly` must be length 16 or one, not 3.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are only 16 points, I would be tempted to create a 1:1 mapping and just create a new factor to replace the old one:

```r
all_points <- c("N", "NNE", "NE", "ENE", "E", "ESE", "SE", "SSE",
                "S", "SSW", "SW", "WSW", "W", "WNW", "NW", "NNW")

full <- c("North", "North", "NorthEast", "East", "East", 
          "East", "SouthEast", "South", "South", "South", 
          "SouthWest", "West", "West", "West", "NorthWest", "North")

weather$W.G.Dir <- factor(full[match(weather$W.G.Dir, all_points)], 
                          unique(full))

weather
#>      W.G.Dir
#> 1      South
#> 2       East
#> 3  SouthEast
#> 4      North
#> 5      North
#> 6       West
#> 7  SouthEast
#> 8  SouthWest
#> 9       West
#> 10     North
```

---

**Data made up for example**

```r
set.seed(1)

all_points <- c("N", "NNE", "NE", "ENE", "E", "ESE", "SE", "SSE",
                "S", "SSW", "SW", "WSW", "W", "WNW", "NW", "NNW")

weather <- data.frame(W.G.Dir = factor(sample(all_points, 10, TRUE), all_points))

weather
#>    W.G.Dir
#> 1        S
#> 2      ENE
#> 3       SE
#> 4        N
#> 5      NNE
#> 6        W
#> 7       SE
#> 8       SW
#> 9      WNW
#> 10     NNE
```

Comment: Thank you Allen, the code worker perfectly!